# Django+gunicorn+nginx upload large file connection reset error

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to upload a large file (approx 4GB) to my django website. I use the regular file upload method described in the django docs.  I am serving the website with Nginx -> Gunicorn -> Django on EC2 instance.

Problem
Uploading till 1GB files works fine. It works fine for smaller files but when I try to upload a file of 2GB or more I get a connect reset error in chrome.

Logs & specs
There are nothing informative in logs I can find.

**Versions**:
Django==3.2.4
Nginx==1.20

**Config snippet**:
nginx.conf: ( in the http block)

```
client_max_body_size 4G;
client_body_buffer_size 4096M;
client_body_timeout 300;
```

Am I missing any django configuration?
Hope somebody is able to shed some light on the cause and fix.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you solved yours? If so, how did you do?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a browser limit (es. [chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/110232967/uploading-file-size-limit?hl=en)).

Probably you have to split the file and upload separately.

Comment: Marco, Thanks for the response. But I am afraid its not the case. Chrome supports file upload for a size greater than 4GB. Moreover I have tried with multiple browsers and I get the same error everytime. Unfortunately, our application has to support a single file of 4GB so splitting the file is not an option for me.